# How to make a class that contains all my assets/objects to work with many fragments

Tags: android

I want to make a class which contains all the static objects/assets that I use in many different classes and fragments(classes).
So basically I want to be able to say in a fragment class: Style.example3 when I'm setting a font for a particular TextView.

But I keep getting errors like the path or file is not found in the Style class. I have also tried with extending the Style class with Application and use the context or getAplicationContext.getAssets, without any succses.

Right now I'm creating each asset or font everytime in every fragmentclass they are used in, which is not so good.

```
public class Style {


//-----------------------FONTS------------------------

public Typeface example1 = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/FreeSerif.ttf");
public Typeface example2 = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/Arimo-Regular.ttf");
public Typeface example3 = Typeface.createFromFile("fonts/FreeSerif.ttf");
public Typeface example4 = Typeface.createFromFile("fonts/FreeSerif.ttf");

//------------------------Color backgrounds HEX------------------------


public static String darkgray =  "#373737";
public static String lightgray = "#e6e6e6";
public static String oldpaper =  "#EAE1D8";
public static String lightpink = "#feaec9";
public static String darkpink =  "#ff0f68";
public static String redpink =   "#E849A1";
public static String yellow =    "#F7E84E";
public static String orange =    "#FFB732";
public static String skyblue =   "#48B1E3";
public static String green =     "#5dd95d";
public static String softblack = "#3d3d3d";

//------------------------------------------------------------------------
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't do that kind of things. Good practices in Android advise you to do as many things as possible in XML. So basically, what you could do is create a BaseActivity that extends `AppCompatActivity` and make your activities extend that BaseActivity.

Another thing your can do is to create your own Widget. Example with a custom textview with a custom font.

```
public class CustomTextView extends TextView {

    public CustomTextView(Context c) {
        super(c);
        init(null);
    }

    public CustomTextView(Context c, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(c, attrs);
        init(attrs);
    }

    public CustomTextView(Context c, AttributeSet attrs, int style) {
        super(c, attrs, style);
        init(attrs);
    }

    private void init(AttributeSet attrs) {
        if (attrs != null) {
            TypedArray a = getContext().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.CustomTextView);
            String fontName = a.getString(R.styleable.CustomTextView_font_name);
        if (fontName != null) {
            Typeface myTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/" + fontName);
            setTypeface(myTypeface);
        }
        a.recycle();
    }
}
```

and in your xml layouts :

```
<com.shopmium.views.widgets.CustomTextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/textview"
    app:font_name="Roboto-Medium.ttf" />
```

Finally, use your resource files as many as possible :

- use `styles.xml`
- create a `colors.xml` and use it like this : `R.color.mycolor`

Hope it helps !

Comment: But the users of the app should be able to change the font. Its an app where you can write poems, quotes, etc. So that wouldn't work with XML, furthermore, the fonts are used in a font-menu where you can see the different font if you understand?

Comment: I understand what you want to do. Maybe a good solution would be to create many styles in your styles.xml and set text appearance dynamically according to user choice like this : textView.setTextAppearance(context, R.style.MyTextStyle);

Answer (score -1):

Use static import for the global class and then use the static objects locally. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/static-import.html